# Gettin into the os from this screen

Tags: boot

When I boot I get this:

[image]

What commands should I write to get it working again

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?   Your provided picture appears to be an *outdated bionic* system that would match a 18.04 system behind on security fixes & patches, or you're not using Ubuntu at all.  You should provide OS/release details, as the `busybox` package mentioned isn't used by *upgraded* and *supported* Ubuntu OSes   (ie. closest I see is `busybox | 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.4  | bionic-security/universe | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x`)

Comment: Yes I am using Ubuntu

Comment: Ubuntu isn't very helpful alone, product & release details are also helpful.  eg. as per my prior comment your `busybox` version isn't from a *supported* release of Ubuntu being outdated; meaning you're either using an *unsupported* release of Ubuntu (thus off-topic) or as I suggested in prior comment, a *bionic* system that is just rather behind on security fixes (eg. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/busybox/1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.4 will show it was a 2021 upload so not very recent)

Comment: Try the command `exit`